# How to put variables in const char *array and make size a variable

Tags: c, arrays, char, constants

I have this array which is correct, but I need the values and size to be variable. Is this possible? If so, how?

```
const char *labels[] = { "Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D", "Group E", "Group F", "Group G", "Group H" };
```

It has to be a `const char *` array because it is being used as a stringArray parameter, which won't take anything less complicated.

Any help would be appreciated. Please keep in mind that I am a student developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It has to be a const char *array because it is being used as a
>   stringArray parameter, which won't take anything less complicated.

You can pass `char*` to function expecting `const char*`.

Given that, maybe you can try something like this:

```
char**arr = malloc(ARRAY_LEN * sizeof(char*));
for (i=0; i<ARRAY_LEN; i++)
{
     arr[i] = malloc(EACH_STRING_LEN);
     if(arr[i]==NULL) 
        handleError();
     strcpy(arr[i],"test"); // put some string in i-th array
}
```

and freeing part:

```
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN; i++) {
  free(arr[i]);
}
free(arr);
```

Comment: Op says it has to be a `const char *`

Comment: @Julien-L: see my comment

Comment: You right, I had `char* const*` in mind and then it would have caused problems when putting something in the strings. I +1 you.

Comment: This worked, @Giorgi. Thanks! I had to delay working on this part, so sorry for the slow reply.

Comment: @NerdMom: glad if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

c arrays do not have variable size. If you need this functionality, you have to use a different data structure

What do you mean by "it is being used as a stringArray parameter, which won't take anything less complicated."?

Comment: Here is the function that uses it:                                                                TextBox *setLabels(StringArray labels)
 { TextBox *ret = new TextBox(CAxis_setLabels(ptr, labels.data,    labels.len)); reg(ret); return ret; }